# Spark dataframe update column where other colum is like with PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This creates my example dataframe:

```
df = sc.parallelize([('abc',),('def',)]).toDF() #(
df = df.selectExpr("_1 as one",)
df = df.withColumn("two", lit('z'))
df.show()
```

looking like this:

```
+---+---+
|one|two|
+---+---+
|abc|  z|
|def|  z|
+---+---+
```

now what I want to do is a series of `SQL where like` statements where column `two` is appended whether or not it matches

in "pseudo code" it looks like this:

```
for letter in ['a','b','c','d']:
    df = df['two'].where(col('one').like("%{}%".format(letter))) += letter
```

finally resulting in a df looking like this:

```
+---+----+
|one| two|
+---+----+
|abc|zabc|
|def|  zd|
+---+----+
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using a list of strings to subset your string column, you can best use `broadcast` variables. Let's start with a more realistic example where your string still contain spaces:

```
df = sc.parallelize([('a b c',),('d e f',)]).toDF()
df = df.selectExpr("_1 as one",)
df = df.withColumn("two", lit('z'))
```

Then we create a `broadcast` variable from a list of letters, and consequently define an `udf` that uses them to subset a list of strings; and finally concatenates them with the value in another column, returning one string:

```
letters = ['a','b','c','d']
letters_bd = sc.broadcast(letters) 

def subs(col1, col2):

    l_subset =  [x for x in col1 if x in letters_bd.value]
    return col2 + ' ' + ' '.join(l_subset)

subs_udf = udf(subs)
```

To apply the above, the string we are subsetting need to be converted to a list, so we use the function `split()` first and then apply our `udf`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, split

df.withColumn("three", split(col('one'), r'\W+')) \
  .withColumn("three", subs_udf("three", "two")) \
  .show()
+-----+---+-------+
|  one|two|  three|
+-----+---+-------+
|a b c|  z|z a b c|
|d e f|  z|    z d|
+-----+---+-------+
```

Or without `udf`, using `regexp_replace` and `concat` if your letters can be comfortably fit into the `regex` expression.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace, col, concat, lit

df.withColumn("three", concat(col('two'), lit(' '), 
              regexp_replace(col('one'), '[^abcd]', ' ')))
```

Comment: `expr` with `regexp_replace` could be a better choice performance wise. And in 2.1+ you can use [`regexp_replace` alone](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.1.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala#L2324)

Comment: yes valid answer but it is sadly impractical for the application I'm working on. Sorry i did not specify this. I got over 10 million documents (in `one`) and a nested `dictionary` with over 5 Million key words i want to match them against and caputer the result in `two`. Regex was my first approach but `like` and `is in` is way faster so i tried to find a solution incorporating them.

Comment: so then column `one` consists of sentences where you are filtering for specific words? and you append words(?) from `two` to the result?

Comment: Yes. Basically I have an initial list of words I'm looking for in `one` if this word appears in `one` I append it to `two`. The idea being that I have a nested dictionary looking like this: `dict[word][word][word] = some_id`. Now I want all the keys from the top level dictonary that match on `one` be stored in `two` to later repeat the processes for the deeper levels of the dictionary lastly arriving at the `some_id`.

Comment: that looks very help full thanks! will try it out later